# Number theory hcf confusion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I need to show 11|(100a+b) if and only if 11|(a+b).

The solution:

11|(100a+b) iff 11|(100a+b-99a) so obviously 11|(a+b) and we have the solution as easily as that.
However I cannot see why this is true.

Comment: Which first step?

Comment: In general $m$ divides $x+qm$ if and only if $m$ divides $x$.

Comment: Your argument is correct. Your solution itself implies why this is true

Comment: "so obviously" should be "iff", i.e. $\,11\mid 11n\!+\!k\iff 11\mid k,\ $ or $\ 11\mid a\iff 11\mid (a\ {\rm mod}\ 11),\ $ or if $\  a\equiv b\pmod{11}\ $ then $\ 11\mid a\iff 11\mid b.\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
11 &\mid (100a+b)\\
\iff 11 &\mid (99a+a+b) \\
\iff 11 &\mid 99a+(a+b) \\
\text{and we know that }11 &\mid 99a\\
\iff11 &\mid (a+b) \\
\end{align}$$